# List and Compare data types between two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames where the count and headers of the columns are supposed to match. But the column data type may be different. 
I want to be able to list out the columns as per the data type and then compare between the two, again giving me a list of column headers whose data types are not matching.

For example, I have two data frames - df1 and df2. DF1 is like below where

- Geometry has the geometry data type
- A is an integer
- B is string

| Geometry | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 1 | x |
| 78.900 | 2 | b |

And in DF2, A is a string, whereas it should be an integer (like in DF1)

I have tried getting the count of the columns based on data types, and was able to get so using `df1.dtypes.value_counts()`
 I have also tried groupby to list all the column names based on the data type using 
`g = df1.columns.to_series().groupby(df1.dtypes).groups` 
 But in order to use the groupby, I have to delete the geometry column from the df as it is throwing a TypeError for this. I managed to get the list after creating a new df where I dropped the geometry column. 
 I want to now compare the two dataframes and their columns' data types, and list the same. 
I also tried using equals like `df1.equals(df2)` which provided `FALSE`.

Comment: It would be more explicit to provide DataFrame constructors for your two inputs, this will avoid any ambiguity on the types

Comment: If column `A` in `df2` should be an integer, you can cast it into an integer with the `astype()` function. Like so `df["A"] = df["A"].astype(int)`

Comment: @MarceloPaco My aim is to identify the differences and then take the call. I do not want to directly apply the changes. But your comment will surely help me when i want to convert the data type!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two data frames have the same number of columns and same column names, this will give you the list of column names for which the dtypes are different:

```
dt = (df1.dtypes.sort_index() == df2.dtypes.sort_index())

dt.loc[dt == False].index.to_list()
```

Comment: The same number of columns are present with the same names but they're not in the same sequence. Trying your code gave me this error - ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: Oh, I did not think about that! I edited the code so it will work whatever the order of the columns.